# Google Maps, Making markers show at different zoom levels?

Tags: google-maps-markers

I've got a Google map with around 1000 makers, I need to make it so when at a higher zoom level they are not all shown and then when zooming in they start to show.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Marker Manager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html)?